# how to remove duplicate data from sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to remove the duplicate row from this SQL and twice product code are passing. I want a common data from this SQL. I m running this SQL in PostgreSQL database.

The SQL query is :

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  csi.style_item_id AS id,  
  csi.item_code AS item_code,  
  csi.quantity AS quantity,  
  std_unit.stdum_name AS standard_unit,  
  csi.total_cost AS total_cost,  
  cim.item_name AS item_name,  
  pid.product_code AS product_code  
FROM cm_items_master cim,  
  cm_style_items csi,  
  stdunit_master std_unit,  
  cm_style_ccode_master sccm,  
  cm_style_designer sd,  
  cm_designer_master dm,  
  cm_production_info_details pid  
WHERE pid.style_ccode_id = sccm.style_ccode_id  
  AND csi.cm_item_id  = cim.item_id  
  AND csi.std_unit_id  = std_unit.id  
  AND csi.style_ccode_id   = sccm.style_ccode_id  
  AND sccm.style_ccode_id  = sd.style_ccode_id  
  AND sd.designer_id  = dm.designer_id  
  AND pid.product_code     IN (  getSplitedPdtCode(productCode) )  
  AND csi.is_delete        = 'N'
  AND cim.is_delete        = 'N'  
  AND std_unit.is_delete   = 'N'
```

This SQL returns same row 4 time. I don't want the duplicate data.

Comment: Hell. Is it this too complicated to use proper case etc?

Comment: No, it is not possible that a `select distinct` results with duplicate rows. Can you please show some data sample.

Comment: Unrelated, but: please get used to explicit `JOIN`s rather than using the old, implicit joins in the `where` clause

Comment: Please add some some sample data and the expected output based on that data (**edit** your question)

Answer (score 0):

try this query, it will help you.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  csi.style_item_id AS id,  
  csi.item_code AS item_code,  
  csi.quantity AS quantity,  
  std_unit.stdum_name AS standard_unit,  
  csi.total_cost AS total_cost,  
  cim.item_name AS item_name,  
  pid.product_code AS product_code  
FROM (cm_items_master cim,  
  cm_style_items csi,  
  stdunit_master std_unit,  
  cm_style_ccode_master sccm,  
  cm_style_designer sd,  
  cm_designer_master dm,  
  cm_production_info_details pid) A
WHERE pid.style_ccode_id = sccm.style_ccode_id  
  AND csi.cm_item_id  = cim.item_id  
  AND csi.std_unit_id  = std_unit.id  
  AND csi.style_ccode_id   = sccm.style_ccode_id  
  AND sccm.style_ccode_id  = sd.style_ccode_id  
  AND sd.designer_id  = dm.designer_id  
  AND pid.product_code     IN (  getSplitedPdtCode(productCode) )  
  AND csi.is_delete        = 'N'
  AND cim.is_delete        = 'N'  
  AND std_unit.is_delete   = 'N'
  AND CTID in (select max(CTID) from A group by id)
```

Answer (score 0):

A best possible way to remove duplication in SQL

```
Row_Number() over ( partition by <add a list of columns which you wanted to be unique in each row> order by <list of columns which you wanted to order by> ) as row
```

Store above result in a temp table and select data from temp table where row=1 which will give you unique rows for listed columns on a partition by clause.

Answer (score -1):

```
With CTE_Dup as emp
    (Select *, row_number() over(partition by Empid order by Empid) as rownumber 
    from employee)
Delete from emp
where rownuber > 1
```

Comment: Code only answers are very low quality because there should always be at least one or two sentences explaining to the reader what question you're answering, and in what way this code answers that question.  See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272/is-there-any-benefit-to-allowing-code-only-answers-while-blocking-code-only-ques